# AWS Android - Store file in S3 with properties

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Can someone show me how to upload a file in AWS S3 with Android, while having properties on that file such as 'File Name', 'File Path', 'FileType' etc.  I'm aware i need to create a bucket on the back-end, which i have done, and set the properties, i just need the Android code for the latest (un-deprecated) way to do this.

Also, can you tell me how to download that file and properties, assuming the file is set to Public access.

Thanks

Comment: u can take a look at this link, it will help you a bit. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Comment: I solved this by using DynamoDB to hold my records for each file stored in S3